# Upload files from dropbox/box account to a public cloud using an iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I need to transfer files from the drop box account directly to a public cloud without downloading the files and storing it in the application sandbox. Does Apple allow this?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the same and did not find it. It should not be due to Apple allowing or not; but dropbox app does not have the function. E.g. to send a photo from dropbox, sharing function only sends a link in my apple mail.

Only possible solution I am exploring is using airfile (not sure of other apps AFAIK now), clicking on sharing allows me to open it in other app (buggy 4 my test nw) or to send via email.. send via email sounds ok since i can select photos in airfile, see the actual pic in the apple mail and send it via to flickr.

Hope that idea helps!